# How to reverse audio wave using processing

Tags: audio, reverse, processing, analog-digital-converter

Is there a way to analyize the audio recorded by the application and reverse its wave? for example in Analog Audio the wave of sound is like a sinwave either 0,1,-1. I want to reverse that so that 1 will be -1 and the -1 be 1. How to do that using processing software?

Comment: If you're trying to go for some acoustic effect, this won't change how the file sounds at all-- inverting the signal will sound exactly the same to the human ear.

Comment: What you're describing is inversion, not reversion (reversing the wave would mean playing it backwards.) Most software has wave invert functionality. In Audacity, for example, you simply select "Invert" in the "Effect" menu. With that being said, this question is off-topic on SO, since it seems you're not talking about doing this programmatically, but through end-user software.

Answer (score 1):

Nikos is correct that the operation you are looking for is called Invert and not reverse. This achieved simply by multiplying every sample by -1.

The best way to do this is to use Minim, processing's audio library. You can extend the UGen class in order to make a new effects processor that flips every sample that goes through it. I've included an example below that works with a sine wave. You can change this around to be some other audio source and to draw it however you like.

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioOutput out;

void setup()
{
  size(300, 200, P2D);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  out = minim.getLineOut();

  Oscil osc;
  Invert inv;
  Constant cutoff;

  // initialize the oscillator 
  // (a sawtooth wave has energy across the spectrum)
  osc = new Oscil(500, 0.2, Waves.SINE);  
  inv = new Invert();
  osc.patch(inv).patch(out);
}

void draw()
{
  background( 0 );

}

public class Invert extends UGen{

  public UGenInput audio;

  Invert()
  {
    audio = new UGenInput(InputType.AUDIO);
  }

  @Override
  protected void uGenerate (float[] channels)
  {
    if ( audio.isPatched() )
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++){
        // this is where we multiple each sample by -1
        channels[i] = audio.getLastValues()[i] * -1;
      } 
    }  
  }
}
```